# How to pass List<object> via MultipartFormDataContent c#

Tags: c#, api, multipartform-data

I am trying to understand how to make API calls with MultipartFormDataContent. So far I have been able to send variabels and Lists with strings but whenever I try to send a list with ints or list with classes the API retrieves an empty list.

How do I send it?

This is my code that works:

```
        var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass.steps); //this is list of string with steps

        multiForm.Add(new StringContent(testEmployee.UserID.ToString()), "UserID");       
        multiForm.Add(new StringContent(json), "steps");
```

So how do I send a list of ints or list of Employees?
I tried doing the same like above but it didn't work. The API then retrieves an empty list.

Comment: Look at sample of MIME at following.  I MIME attachment is a new line starting with two dashes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

```
var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass.steps); //this is list of string with steps

multiForm.Add(new StringContent(testEmployee.UserID.ToString()), "UserID");       
multiForm.Add(new StringContent(json), "steps");
```

to service

```
[HttpPost("MyFunction")]
public IActionResult MyFunction([FromForm] string steps)
{
   List<step> models= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<step>>(steps);
}
```